# Unable to attach div after detaching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-audio

I have a div than contains audio player. When submitting the form, it will clone the div and remove the original div so that when new link is fetched from the server cloned div will be attached to the audio source with new link. I'm unable to attach the div after removing it although the clone div exists. I've checked if the cloned div exists, and it exsits. I'm trying to play audio based on new user request. Data is successfully fetched from the server.

This is the div

```
<div class="audioDiv">
    <audio controls="controls" id="audioplayer">
        <source src="" type="audio/mp3" class="audioSource"/>
        <source src="" type="audio/ogg" class="audioSource"/>
    </audio>
</div>
```

This is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
$("#loading").hide();

var form = $('#player-form');

var u;
form.submit(function (e) {
    var cloneDiv = $("#audioplayer").detach();
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        dataType : 'json',
        timeout : 100000,
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#loading").show();
        },
        complete:function(){
            $("#loading").hide();
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data.link);
            $(".audioSource").attr('src',data.link);

            $(cloneDiv).appendTo('.audioDiv');

            console.log(cloneDiv);

            plyr.setup();

        },
        error : function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: From the logic it seems like the re-attaching should work fine, since you are not removing the '#audioDiv'.  One part that concerns me is your trying to update the audioSource with a global selector, but that field belonged as a child of the element you detached, so it shouldn't find it.  You'll want to find the audioSource within the cloneDiv to update them, before re-attaching.

Comment: I updated the code and now it appends new audio element on every response. audioSource is working as I moved $(cloneDiv).appendTo('.audioDiv'); before $(".audioSource").attr('src',data.link); . I think I need to check if audio elements is present, if not present create new audio element. Any Idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have id of audioDiv

```
$(cloneDiv).appendTo('.audioDiv');
cloneDiv.appendTo('.audioDiv');
```

Comment: code changed as mentioned, my bad. Now, everytime I submit form, new player is created.